# Is there a metrics endpoint for thanos querier which shows all the metrics from the stores and not just thanos itself?

Tags: prometheus, thanos

I tried using '/metrics' on thanos querier url, but I only see the thanos metrics. Is there a way to view the store metrics using an endpoint?

Answer (score -2):

recommend you care metrics of '/metrics' ，if you found the 'thanos_store_nodes_grpc_connections{external_labels="",store_type="sidecar"}', mean some endpoints are disconnect.